# Is this 1977 “thank you” letter from Joe Biden real?

Tags: united-states, politics, racism, document-authenticity

The following letter (dated June 30, 1977) claiming to be from Joe Biden is currently floating around social media. Is this real?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## It appears to be real and not just on “social” media.

[CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/04/11/politics/joe-biden-busing-letters-2020/index.html) treats this letter as genuine: Letters from Joe Biden reveal how he sought support of segregationists in fight against busing:

> “Dear Mr. Chairman,” Biden wrote on June 30, 1977. “I want you to know that I very much appreciate your help during this week’s committee meeting in attempting to bring my anti-busing legislation to a vote.”
> <sub>[–– Letters from Joe Biden reveal how he sought support of segregationists in fight against busing. By Jeff Zeleny, Senior Washington Correspondent
> Updated 1149 GMT (1949 HKT) June 28, 2019](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/04/11/politics/joe-biden-busing-letters-2020/index.html)</sub>

[*The Washington Post*](https://www.washingtonpost.com/context/joe-biden-s-letters-to-segregationist-sen-james-o-eastland/705b015f-bd0a-4d7d-84e5-88960d5667a7/?) had a few of these documents, including:

> [image: Image of the letter from The Washington Post.]
> The letters were obtained from the University of Mississippi, which houses Sen. James O. Eastland’s archived papers.
>
> The correspondence from 1972 to 1978 shows Joe Biden, at the time a young senator, trying to establish a relationship with Eastland, a staunch segregationist. The letters highlight Biden’s committee assignments and antibusing legislation.
> <sub>[–– Washington Post: Joe Biden’s letters to segregationist Sen. James O. Eastland, Updated Jun 21, 2019 at 3:28 AM](https://www.washingtonpost.com/context/joe-biden-s-letters-to-segregationist-sen-james-o-eastland/705b015f-bd0a-4d7d-84e5-88960d5667a7/?)  ([PDF](https://games-cdn.washingtonpost.com/notes/prod/default/documents/e350deaa-91a4-47b3-bcb8-9a86be48763f/note/bc5bda3e-8256-4313-acf7-6a0d29db51c3.pdf))</sub>

And finally, while Biden sees a few qualifiers to be applicable for how, why etc he supported the policy back then, when confronted in a recent debate, Joe Biden knew what it was about and didn’t bring up doubt over any authenticity:

> [Time: Kamala Harris Hit Joe Biden on His Civil Rights Record. Here’s What to Know About Biden's History With Busing](https://time.com/5616709/joe-biden-busing-democratic-debate/)

Comment: Here's an article with the full context, if anyone is interested. Summary is that Biden was extremely influential in stopping busing, and his segregationist allies were very helpful. https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2015/08/04/joe-biden-integration-school-busing-120968